# How to catch "NotesException: Notes error: Remote system no longer responding" and retry?

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I have this java agent that processes a huge amount of documents that it could run overnight. The problem is that I need the agent to retry if the network got suddenly disconnected briefly. The retry could have a maximum number.

```
int numberOfRetries = 0;
try {
    while(nextdoc != null) {
        // process documents
        numberOfRetries = 0;
    }
} catch (NotesException e) {
    numberOfRetries++;
    if (numberOfRetries > 4) {
        // go back and reprocess current document
    } else {
        // message reached max number of retries. did not successfully finished
    }
}
```

Also, of course I do not want to actually retry the whole process. Basically I need to continue on the document it was processing and move on to the next loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do a retry loop around each piece of code that gets a document.  Since the Notes classes generally require a getFirst and getNext paradigm, that means you need two separate retry loops. E.g.,

```
   numberOfRetries = 0;
   maxRetries = 4;   

   // get first document, with retries

   needToRetry = false;
   while (needToRetry)
   {
      try
      {
         while (needToRetry)
         {
            nextDoc = myView.getFirstDocument();
            needToRetry=false;
         }    
      }
      catch (NotesException e) 
      {
         numberOfRetries++;
         if (numberOfRetries < maxRetries) {
            // you might want to sleep here to wait for the network to recover
            // you could use numberOfRetries as a factor to sleep longer on
            // each failure
            needToRetry = true;
         } else {
            // write "Max retries have been exceeded getting first document" to log
            nextDoc = null; // we won't go into the processing loop 
         }
      }
   }

   // process all documents

   while(nextdoc != null) 
   {

      // process nextDoc
      //   insert your code here


      // now get next document, with retries

      while (needToRetry)
      {
         try
         {
            nextDoc = myView.getNextDocument();
            needToRetry=false;
         }  
         catch (NotesException e) 
         {
            numberOfRetries++;
            if (numberOfRetries < maxRetries) {
               // you might want to sleep here to wait for the network to recover
               // you could use numberOfRetries as a factor to sleep longer on
               // each failure
               needToRetry = true;
            } else {
               // write "Max retries have been exceeded getting first document" to log
               nextDoc = false; // we'lll be exiting the processing loop without finishing all docs 
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Note that I'm treating maxRetries as the max total retries across all documents in the data set, not the max for each document.

Also note that it's probably cleaner to break this up a little.  E.g.

```
   numberOfRetries = 0;
   maxRetries = 4;  

   nextDoc = getFirstDocWithRetries(view);   // this contains while loop and try-catch

   while (nextDoc != null)
   { 
       processOneDoc(nextDoc);
       nextDoc = getNextDocWithRetries(view,nextDoc);   // and so does this
   }
```

Comment: As Simon has pointed out, my code above makes an unsafe assumption that the NotesException that has been thrown is due to the "server not responding" error that the OP is asking about. Given the context, my experience tells me that if the code in the agent is otherwise working properly, then this is in fact the most likely case, but Simon is correct that there are other potential causes, and attempting to recover from some of them could do more harm than good.

Comment: Since I'm not 100% certain what the NotesException.id and NotesException.text values will be for a transient network fault, I'm not updating the code in my answer. However, I think the values will be id=4000 & text="Notes erorr: server not responding".

Comment: It might be safer to recreate Notes objects like db, view and collection after NotesException. For this you would save the UNID of current document in a variable outside the try-catch-block. Inside the block you'd create db, view and collection and start to work in collection at saved document UNID. This way you don't depend on state of NotesObjects after NotesException as you create them new from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend what you are doing at all.

The NotesException can fire for a number of reasons, and there is no guarantee you will be returning to a safe state.

Also the fact the agent needs to run for such a long time means you need to change the server "Maximum execution timeout" to allow it to run correctly. Setting that to a very high value makes the server more prone to performance/deadlock issues.

A better solution would be to batch workload and have the agent run for a set time on a batch. Update as you go so that when the agent comes back it knows to work on the next batch.

Comment: Simon, I think it wasn't necessary that you downvoted Richard's answer as this is a correct and useful answer to the question. I voted him up so he has the former number of upvotes again. Your answer is useful too and answers the question from a larger point of view.

Comment: Neither answers posted were correct, and liable to cause serious problems (one has since been deleted). The answers are based on the flawed assumption of the OP that NotesException equates to only a network timeout. Even if it was the case, there is no guarantee the notes back end objects will be in a stable state to use. So, no Richards answer is not a correct answer.

Comment: With respect, Simon, I disagree. Recovering from exceptions is a common requirement. You can't just expect customers to stop everything when they hit one. Some applications just aren't suitable for batching (due to high startup overhead, impact on other non-Domino systems, narrow time windows, etc.). Rather than suggesting that the OP abandon his entire approach, you could have added a comment pointing out that it would be wise to check NotesException.id and NotesException.text make a smarter choice about when to do a retry.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (but not certain) that it would be e.id=4000 & e.text="Server not responding" in the case of a network interruption.

Comment: It tells you the error, but it doesn't tell you anything about the state of the server to get to that point, nor the state of your referenced objects when it comes back (if it comes back). Eg, latency, drop users, fix up/compact (more likely at night). Only the first option may work with the code. When a NotesException is thrown, it should be about reporting/clean up, not reusing the same objects.